# Android alert dialog error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an alert dialog popup and have tried several different methods, they all result in this error.
"android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

dialog requires activity context, any other context will throw this exception
   `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`